Is it always possible to embed a symplectic manifold into some $T^*Q$?
I've read this question asking about whether it is always possible to embed a symplectic manifold into $(\mathbb{R}^{2n},\omega)$ for some $n$, the answer is negative because $\omega$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$.
I'm then curious whether given an arbitrary symplectic manifold $\Gamma$ it is always possible to find some manifold $Q$ such that $\Gamma$ can be embedded in the cotangent bundle $T^*Q$.
If the answerer is physically inclined, my motivation for asking this is to know whether any symplectic manifold (or Hamiltonian phase space) could in principle be realized in terms of Hamiltonian constraints. I'm curious about what the failure of such an embedding theorem could mean for Hamiltonian systems (maybe a Hamiltonian system that is not a Legendre transform of a Lagrangian system in any sense?).

Since the symplectic form on $T^Q$ is exact, you can only hope to embed exact symplectic manifolds as in the case of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$. You could alter the question by asking about the case with a magnetic field, i.e. $\omega=\omega_{can}+\pi^\beta$ for $\beta$ a small closed form on the base.
